# powershell : create column in a group

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfield

Like described in the title, i'm writing a powershell script that create a content type and some column.
The issue is that my columns are not in the specified group but in group "custom column"
Here is what i do

```
$web.fields.add($myColumn, "Text", $false)
$field = $web.fields.getfield($argFieldName)
$field.Group = "test"
$fieldLink = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink($field)
$argCType.fieldlinks.add($fieldLink)
```

What i do wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the field after setting the group value

```
$web.fields.add($myColumn, "Text", $false)
$field = $web.fields.getfield($argFieldName)
$field.Group = "test"
$field.Update()
$fieldLink = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink($field)
$argCType.fieldlinks.add($fieldLink)
```

Comment: great it workd :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can try following :

```
$siteColl = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://engchesqltemp/"
$rootWeb = $siteColl.RootWeb
#Assign fieldXMLString variable with field XML for site column
$fieldXMLString = '<Field Type="Text"
Name="LocalServiceReview"
Description="Indicate date of last and next meeting and names of current members."
DisplayName="Local Service Review Team"
StaticName="LocalServiceReview"
Group="Portman Applications"
Hidden="FALSE"
Required="FALSE"
Sealed="FALSE"
ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"
ShowInEditForm="TRUE"
ShowInListSettings="TRUE"
ShowInNewForm="TRUE"></Field>'
#See field XML on console
write-host $fieldXMLString
#Create site column from XML string
$rootWeb.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($fieldXMLString)
```